# reactJs onClick handler not working

Tags: reactjs

Although defining onClick handler properly, console.log('hi') is not printing on console

```
import React from 'react';
import './charComponent.css'
const CharOne = (props) =>{
 return (<div>
 <div className="charOne" onClick={console.log('hi')}>{props.letter}</div>
 </div>
 )
}
export default CharOne;
```

Comment: `<div className="charOne" onClick={e => console.log('hi')}>`

Answer (score 2):

console.log('hi') is immediately invoking,

> > so your onClick has nothing to do (no job).   See below code.

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const myFunction = () => console.log('hi');

const CharOne = () => <div onClick={myFunction}>Click-Me</div>

ReactDOM.render(<CharOne />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

> > If you want to pass an argument,  then use an arrow function.

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const myFunction = props => console.log(props);

const CharOne = () => <div onClick={() => myFunction('Hello')}>Click-Me</div>

ReactDOM.render(<CharOne />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a function as parameter:

```
import React from 'react';
import './charComponent.css'
const CharOne = (props) =>{
 return (<div>
 <div className="charOne" onClick={() => console.log('hi')}>{props.letter}</div>
 </div>
 )
}
export default CharOne;
```